# Custom woocommerce product field not working for CSV import

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I've created a custom field for my products this way:

```
// The code for displaying WooCommerce Product Custom Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields' ); 
// Following code Saves  WooCommerce Product Custom Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save' );
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields () {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class=" product_custom_field ">';
    // Custom Product Number Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_shipping_days_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Días de entrega',
            'label' => __('Días estimados de entrega', 'woocommerce'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '1'
            )
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id){
    // Custom Product Number Field
    $shipping_days = $_POST['_shipping_days_field'];
    if (!empty($shipping_days))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_shipping_days_field', esc_attr($shipping_days));
}
```

This is working ok on the frontend admin it shows the field and saves it, but it is not working for the CSV impornt, I cannot specify the field in my CSV mapping. Is there a way I can create custom field that works for CSV import as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved it, on the mapping you just should select Meta Attributes, and the label on the CSV column must be as follows:

`meta:your_custom_field`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more ? I am not able to find the meta attributes option in mapping